# How to test values returned by get() method of YUI3?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, yui, yui3

I would like to mock an object like this:

```
var target = new Y.Mock(),
    eventObject = {};

Y.Mock.expect(target, {
    method: 'get',
    args: ['actionId'],
    returns: 'edit'
});

Y.Mock.expect(target, {
    method: 'get',
    args: ['container'],
    returns: '<div></div>'
});

eventObject.target = target;
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Argument 0 of get() is incorrect.
Expected: container (string)
Actual: actionId (string)"
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking briefly at the [Y.Mock code](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/test_js_Mock.js.html#l45) code, it looks to me like you cannot create two expectations on the same method, with the same arguments. The latter overwrites the first.

But that's okay, we can just do a bit of the mocking ourselves:

```
var mockedGet = function (args) {
    if (args === 'container') {
        return '<div></div>';
    } else if (args === 'actionId') {
        return 'edit';
    } else {
        YUITest.Assert.fail('Method get('+args+') should not have been called.');
    }

    // we could also verify call counts etc, using the mock object as 'this'
}
Y.Mock.expect(target, {
    method: 'get',
    args: [YUITest.Mock.Value.String], // accepts only one String
    run: mockedGet // replaces returns
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uhm0ffmd/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I've created a similar solution but without calling fail() method. Your version is better than mine.